# jQuery: how to add parameter to a callback function without losing default parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

I have this code:

```
var callbackAfterLoad = function(data, ecBlock) {
    ecBlock.html(data);
    ecBlock.slideDown();
}

function bindevents(userInput, ecBlock, callbackAfterLoad) {
    userInput.keyup(function () {
        delay(function () {
            $.post("/preview", {content:userInput.val()}, callbackAfterLoad(data, ecBlock));
        }, 500);
    });
 }
```

And this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

But when I check out jQuery examples

```
$.post("test.php", function(data) {
  alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});
```

Why do I got this error ? Why do jQuery example is working and not mine ? (we cannot add parameters ?). Is the default $.post callback defined and his signature cannot be overriden ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The third argument in `$.post` should be a function, but when you do this:

```
$.post("/preview", {content:userInput.val()}, callbackAfterLoad(data, ecBlock))
```

The third argument is not the function, but the *return value* of the function. Like this:

```
fn = callbackAfterLoad   // function reference
fn = callbackAfterLoad() // function execution and return value reference
```

And when executed in your example, `data` is not available yet. The correct syntax would be:

```
$.post("/preview", {content:userInput.val()}, callbackAfterLoad)
```

If you need to pass custom arguments to your callback, you can create a new proxy function like this:

```
var callback = function(data) {
    callbackAfterLoad.call(this, data, ecBlock);
};
$.post("/preview", {content:userInput.val()}, callback);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.post` method in little bit another way:

```
$.post("/preview", {content:userInput.val()}, function(data){ callbackAfterLoad(data, ecBlock)} );
```

Your example doesn't work because you're immediately calling to `callbackAfterLoad` , before the `.post` actually "happens" and returns data. In jQuery example the callback function is only registered as handler but not firing immediately.

Comment: Thanks! This is actually working great! But why "function(data)" cannot be called with another anonymous function ?

Comment: @YoH what do you mean exactly. when it goes like this: `function(data){ callbackAfterLoad(data, ecBlock)}` it is actually creates anonymous function that uses data which `post` returns and `ecBlock` that came as `bindevents` function argument